# Unable to extend my input bar with width 100% and align to center

Tags: html, css, spring-boot, bootstrap-4

I'm designing a webpage in jsp file using spring boot. I've used bootstrap for my design. I'm unable to extend my input box to width:100% in both login and new registration page.Also I'm unable to bring my input field to the center.

I've shared my css and html code below.
Please find the error and help me out!

This is my CSS code

```
<style media="screen">
    body{
   margin: 0;
   padding:auto;
   text-align: center;
   font-family:'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
   background-image:linear-gradient(120deg,#b134eb,#5efff7);
   min-height : 160vh;
   } 
   .form-control{
  display: block;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
   }
   </style>
```

This is my Form in html code

```
<body>[login page output[\]\[1\]][1]
      
       <c:choose>
      <c:when test="${mode=='MODE_REGISTER' }">
            <div class="container text-center">
                <h3>New Registration</h3>
                <hr>
                <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="save-user">
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="${user.id }" />
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3">Username</label>
                        <div class="col-md-7">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username"
                                value="${user.username }" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3">First Name</label>
                        <div class="col-md-7">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstname"
                                value="${user.firstname }" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3">Last Name</label>
                        <div class="col-md-7">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastname"
                                value="${user.lastname }" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3">Age </label>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="age"
                                value="${user.age }" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3">Gender </label>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="Male">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="Male">Male</label>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="gender" id="Female" value="Female">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="Female">Female</label>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3">Password</label>
                        <div class="col-md-7">
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password"
                                value="${user.password }" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group ">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Register" />
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            
            
            
        </c:when> 
        
        
        <c:when test="${mode=='MODE_LOGIN' }">
            <div class="container text-center">
                <h3>User Login</h3>
                <hr>
                <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="/login-user">
                    <c:if test="${not empty error }">
                        <div class="alert alert-danger">
                            <c:out value="${error }"></c:out>
                        </div>
                    </c:if>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3">Username</label>
                        <div class="col-md-7">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username"
                                value="${user.username }" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3">Password</label>
                        <div class="col-md-7">
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password"
                                value="${user.password }" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group ">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login" />
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </c:when>
    </c:choose>
</body>
```

[This the output of registration form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7eXo3.png)

Please help me out to bring this input field to the center

Comment: to extend input box, change `<div class="col-md-3">` into `<div class="col-md-12">` or better yet `<div class="col-12">`... if they're small in size and you want to make them centered, use `.form-group div { margin:auto; }`

Comment: Thank you I got....btw....I want bring my radio button to the center too...how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to extend input box, change  into  or better yet ... if they're small in size and you want to make them centered, use .form-group div { margin:auto; }

to center the radio buttons, use `display: flex` also

working **snippet** below:

```css
.form-group div {
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="save-user">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="${user.id }" />
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3">Username</label>
    <div class="col-md-7">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" value="${user.username }" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3">First Name</label>
    <div class="col-md-7">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstname" value="${user.firstname }" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3">Last Name</label>
    <div class="col-md-7">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastname" value="${user.lastname }" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3">Age </label>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="age" value="${user.age }" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-12">Gender </label>
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="Male">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="Male">Male</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="gender" id="Female" value="Female">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="Female">Female</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3">Password</label>
    <div class="col-md-7">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" value="${user.password }" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group ">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Register" />
  </div>
</form>
</div>

</c:when>
```

Answer (score 0):

use max-width:100% for full width and for center use the follwonf code

```
.form-group div{
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items:center;
}
```